# Issue configuring JBoss EAP 6.1 with hibernate 3.6

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I'm trying to deploy an EAR file in my local server but it seems it's still trying to use hibernate 4 (the default option, I guess).

What I have already done:

- I've added a hibernate 3 module in $JBOSS_HOME$\modules\org.hibernate\3 with this module.xml file:

> ```
> <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.hibernate" slot="3">
>
>     <resources>
>         <resource-root path="hibernate3.jar"/>
>         <resource-root path="commons-collections-3.1.jar"/>
>         <resource-root path="jta-1.1.jar"/>
>         <resource-root path="javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar"/>
>         <resource-root path="antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>  
>         <resource-root path="slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"/>  
>         <resource-root path="dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>  
>         <!-- Insert other Hibernate 3 jars to be used here -->
>     </resources>
>
>     <dependencies>
>         <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate" slot="3"/>
>         <module name="asm.asm"/>
>         <module name="javax.api"/>
>         <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
>         <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
>       <module name="com.ibm.db2" />
>         <module name="org.infinispan"/>
>
>
>     </dependencies>
> </module>
> ```

- I've created the data source in `standalone-full-ha.xml`:

> ```
> <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/txdb" pool-name="txdbDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
>     <connection-url>jdbc:db2://156.24.30.103:50000/TX_LSPDB</connection-url>
>
>     <driver>DB2Driver</driver>
>     <security>
>         <user-name> .... </user-name>
>         <password> .... </password>
>     </security>
> </datasource>
> ```

- My persistence.xml file has the following entry:

> ```
> <persistence-unit name="esdb">
>  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
>  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/txdb</jta-data-source>
>  <class>com.gtech.commerce.UidBlockPool</class>       
>  <properties>
>    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect"/>          
>    <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:3" />
>  </properties>
> </persistence-unit>
> ```

And this is what I get when I try to deploy:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalJtaDataSourceConnectionProvider incompatible with org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider  at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:189) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.SP1-redhat-1]   ... 107 more`

Any idea about what I am missing?

UPDATE: I haven't found a solution, so I did the obvious workaround: I am using hibernate 3 bundled with the application, ignoring any module

Answer (score 0):

Imho the problem comes from the fact that the jboss datasource built-in connection pool rely on the default persistence implementation provided with the server.

you can try to override the server datasource configuration

see https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_BRMS_Platform/5/html/BRMS_Administrator_Guide/Configuring_a_Datasource_for_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_6.html

But i don't know if you can specify the connection pool provider.

You could try otherwise to set up a custom datasource

see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html

please consider than you won't be any more in this case:
 `JDBC connections obtained from a JNDI datasource automatically participate in the container-managed transactions of the application server.` 
and will have to properly configure the transaction factory.

As a more general comment I'll advise not to override provided implementation when using a Java EE application server. 
If you wan't to use hibernate 3 switch to Jboss 6.0 or do not rely on the built-in java EE container features (and in this case switch to something lighter like jetty or tomcat)

Comment: I cannot choose the container, actually we are upgrading from JBoss EAP 4 to 6.1. Currently I'm looking the way to modify how the DS is defined in order to ensure hibernate 4 is not used

Comment: Can't you choose at least the minor version ? imho it would be much simpler to upgrade to jboss 6.0